# Stop Numpy rounding small numbers in an array to zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding

I am struggling to use np.array correctly for my coding project in Python.

In essence, I am trying to generate an array from other arrays using nested for loops. I require the output array to be written to **3 decimal places**.

As an example, I have an array **a** which is as following:

```
>>> a
array([[ 34,  25,  76, ..., 143,   5,  95],
       [ 11, 127, 174, ...,  70,  58,  87],
       [174, 182,  24, ..., 115,  70, 180],
       ...,
       [198, 114, 134, ..., 132, 105, 144],
       [ 75,  24,  18, ..., 117,  77, 186],
       [113,  34,  91, ...,   1,  69,  56]])
```

**m** is a *300 by 15* array.

Here is my code:

```
lb = np.array([0]*15)
ub = np.array([1,1,0.5,200,1,1,0.5,200,10,1000,0.5,200,192,192,192])
b  = np.array([0] * (300*15) ).reshape((300, 15))
intervals = np.array([0.005,0.005,0.0025,1,0.005,0.005,0.0025,1,0.05,5,0.0025,1,1,1,1])

for i in range(0,300):

   for j in range(0,15):

      b[i][j] = lb[j] + (a[i][j]*intervals[j])
```

As an output I get:

```
>>> b
array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,  60,  20,  10],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,  70,  58,  87],
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 115,  70, 180],
       ...,
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 132, 105, 144],
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 117,  77, 186],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   1,  69,  56]])
```

Where **b** is a *300 by 15* matrix. However, the 'zeros' in the matrix have been rounded to zero, they **should** be small values between 0 and 1.

How do I stop Numpy from rounding my values to 0 and instead output **b** to 3 decimal places?

I have already tried using **np.around()** and **round()** but neither seem to work.

I have also tested and this is not a 'pretty printing' issue, I have multiplied the array by large numbers and still get a zero.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `b` was created as integer dtype.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I got it working by changing b to an array of 0.1's. This way, I assume Python knows that b is not integer dtype.

Comment: `b =  np.zeros((300, 15), float)` is an easier (and faster) way of creating a float array full of 0s.  And with arrays you can use a cleaner indexing, `b[i, j]`.  Don't forget to read some `numpy` basics.  Don't treat arrays like Python lists.

Comment: Check if `b = lb + a*intervals` does what you want.